# What filesystem type is appropriate for openstack cinder volume?

Tags: openstack, openstack-cinder, block-storage

What filesystem type is appropriate for openstack cinder volume?
How do you go about modifying the cinder service of an already deployed juju charms openstack to work with volumes on an external iSCSI as persistent storage?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

The XFS, btrfs and ext4 file systems provide numerous advantages, XFS was developed for Silicon Graphics, and is a mature and stable filesystem. Beside that btrfs is a copy-on-write filesystem, supports file creation timestamps and checksums that verify metadata integrity, so it can detect bad copies of data and fix them with the good copies,  it support snapshots that are writable , transparent compression and other features.

In case using a ceph storage  better to use an advice: BlueStore